# Dropdownlist does not retain selected value

Tags: jquery, grails, gsp

The value does not retain and it keep go back to 1st value after selection.

This is my jQuery

```
<script>
    if($("#ddlGender").val("Female")) {
        $('select[name^="ddlGender"] option[value="Female"]').attr("selected","selected");
    } else if($("#ddlGender").val("Male")) {
        $('select[name^="ddlGender"] option[value="Male"]').attr("selected","selected");
    } else {
        $('select[name^="ddlGender"] option[value=""]').attr("selected","selected");
    }   
</script>
```

This is my dropdown list

```
<select name="ddlGender" id="ddlGender" onchange="${remoteFunction(action: 'index', controller: 'Main', params:'\'id=\' + escape(this.value)', update: [success: 'd1', failure: 'ohno'], options: '[asynchronous: false]')}">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="Female">Female</option>
  <option value="Male">Male</option>
</select>
```

Comment: **1.** `if($("#ddlGender").val("Female")){` ==> `if($("#ddlGender").val() == "Female"){` **2.** Wrap the code in `ready`, if it is loaded in `<head>`

Answer (score 0):

I am  not exactly understanding why you do `select[name^="ddlGender"]`, cause simple `#ddlGender` can bring you the same result.
Nevertheless, here as I understood you code solution:

```
<select name="ddlGender" id="ddlGender">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
</select>

$('#ddlGender').on('change', function () {
    if ($("#ddlGender option:selected").val()==='Female') {
        $('#ddlGender option[value="Female"]').attr("selected", "selected");
    } else if ($("#ddlGender option:selected").val()==='Male') {
        $('#ddlGender option[value="Male"]').attr("selected", "selected");
    } else {
        $('#ddlGender option[value=""]').attr("selected", "selected");
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLER](http://jsfiddle.net/490xgese/3/)

Hope this helps.